# Get values of nested JSON with unknown names Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, destructuring

I have a deeply nested JSON object with some arbitary value as the name. I can not know the value ahead. A simplified example below. I can't seem to think of a way to get the value I need

```
{
   "bigJSON":{
      "5":{
         "3":[
            {
               "week":{
                  "name":"John",
                  "length":25
               }
            },
            {
               "week":{
                  "name":"John1",
                  "length":95
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "6":{
         "2":[
            {
               "week":{
                  "name":"John3",
                  "length":45
               }
            },
            {
               "week":{
                  "name":"Merlin",
                  "length":25
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I need to get the array from `bigJSON['5']['3'] , bigJSON['6']['2']` etc , but I can't know the values of `5,3,6,2` etc ahead of time. Help will be apprecaited.

Comment: Use `Object.keys` or iterate

Comment: What do you know when you call the script you want to have?

Comment: @mplungjan I only know the name of the json and that it contains the array with the week objects

Comment: I do not understand what you know and not. What is the input and what is expected output?

Comment: How does `getMyData(??,??)` look like

Comment: It’s a JSON returned from a server. Return should  be an array of ‘week’ object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for...in` loop to iterate an object's properties. It looks like you'll need two levels of this iteration based on the structure of your data.

```js
var data = {"bigJSON":{"5":{"3":[{"week":{"name":"John","length":25}},{"week":{"name":"John1","length":95}}]},"6":{"2":[{"week":{"name":"John3","length":45}},{"week":{"name":"Merlin","length":25}}]}}}

var getWeeks = function(data){
  var weeks = []
  for(var level1 in data.bigJSON){
    for(var level2 in data.bigJSON[level1]){
      weeks = weeks.concat(data.bigJSON[level1][level2])
    }
  }
  return weeks;
}

console.log(getWeeks(data))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks @JstnPwll